# E: Package 'libcrystalhd-dev' has no installation candidate,

Tags: ant-media-server-sdk

Package libcrystalhd-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libcrystalhd-dev' has no installation candidate
There is a problem in ins

I tried updating that specific package but it dint work

Answer (score 0):

You can install `libcrystalhd-dev` package by running below command

```
echo "deb http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu   focal universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try reinstalling with the installation script.

However, if you using ARM architecture then it may not be found there.

The ffmpeg script has been updated for AMS v2.6.0 so you can use that directly.